# How do I achieve event based timer?

Tags: java

I am trying to code an event break.
Here is a small piece of code where I am stuck.

```
//some code here
long current_time=System.currentTimeMillis();
long end=current_time+10*1000;//a timer limit of 10 seconds
Packet_ packet_=new Packet_();
while(end>System.currentTimeMillis()){
    packet_ = receivePacket();//System waits for the packet to arrive on the socket in the receivePacket function.
    break;
    }
packet_.printPacketDetails();
//some code here
```

Here, I have set the end variable with a value 10 seconds.

I want to exit the loop on either receiving the packet or the timer going off.

The problem here is, the code comes out of the while loop if the packet arrives, but it does don't come out of the while loop if the current time crosses the end variable.

Comment: run it as a separated thread

Comment: If the call to `receivePacket()` waits for the packet to arrive, then you will not move forward till the packet arrives and will not check the timer till the packet arrives.

Comment: You should call  receivePacket() from a different thread where you can set the timeout.

Comment: basically, in that function, I am using objectReader, nothing else. @clinomaniac

Comment: _ in class names and variables names is an obsolete and bad naming convention, if you have the choice avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Future it's simpler:

```
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Future<Packet> future = executorService.submit(() -> receivePacket());
try {
   Packet packet = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // HANDLE TIMEOUT HERE
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
   // HANDLE FAILURE HERE
}
```

Comment: If I may ask you, how do you know about this class? like I had never heard it before, how do you get to know about these new things?

Comment: I've been a programmer for 7 years and I've worked on lots of projects, but my recommendation is to always search for better solutions using libraries when you have to do something that probably every developers on the planet had to deal with at some point. And also don't just download libraries, download their sources JAR as well and never be afraid to have a look (if you use Maven tell your IDE to download sources, else you can download the sources JAR manually or use GrepCode).